# Lots and lots of floats

Tags: graphics, floats

I am working on a book on statistical graphics.  Needless to say, it has many many figures/floats.  I was (at least as a temporary measure) dumping them all at the end, but even this eventually failed and I had to use a \clearpage . This combination is not good, as it leads to 15 pages of text, 15 pages of floats and then more text.

Is there a way to automatically dump all floats at the end of each section or subsection?

Comment: `\usepackage{endfloat}`

Comment: That gave me an !Undefined control sequence error for 

\@makechapterhead...ent 0pt \vss \chaptitlesize

Comment: Left in the floats as many options as possible (e.g. `[htbp!`]), increase the default number of floats allowed in top/bottom/per page, decrease the % of text allowed. Please see     http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following instruction in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

This will prevent floats encountered in one section from being typeset *after* the next `\section` command is encountered.

Using this instruction doesn't "dump" *all* accumulated floats at the very end of the current section: some floats might get typeset *before* the end of the section.

Comment: Thanks. What do I have to do in the main part of text? Also, I tried with [subsection] and it said that option is not defined in placeins

Comment: @PeterFlom - You're right about the `subsection` option not working; I'll correct that in my answer. If the package is loaded with the `section` option, there's nothing you need to do further. You could, if you wanted, still insert `\FloatBarrier` commands wherever you saw fit. (`FloatBarrier` is a command provided by the `placeins` package.)